# Design spec for faraday cage

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, faraday-cage

I need to build a faraday cage to shield from the following source: 8 Watt, 14 MHz. The signal is AM modulated

I want to build an metal box enclosing the source. I want it to shield the signal so that the AM signal cannot be received, but I want to keep the costs reasonable.

My questions are:

1. I want to use steel, but what should the thickness be? 1mm, 2mm?
2. How should I attach the sides of the box to each other? Is welding acceptable? Or should I use some other method?

Any formulas or reasoning for arriving at an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a spec for how much leakage is allowed? 1% 1/1,000,000, ...?

Comment: Allowed leage is 1%

Comment: What volume? 10cm^3 or 1000m^3 ... makes a cost difference - a metal mint box is ok for a small thing...

Comment: 30cm x 30cm x 30cm

Comment: A fine wire mesh may be sufficient - cheap and easy enough to make and test...

Comment: I understand and agree, but I want to keep my options open to use it for higher frequencies later. So I want a solid surface. My concern is the thickness of sides of the box